# Using SQLite CursorAdapter to populate ListView shows duplicate image in first row

Tags: image, listview, duplicates, android-cursoradapter

I am using a cursor Adapter called TodoCursorAdapter to populate the ListView with Cursor values and also adding an ImageView. Everything works fine, but has a duplicate image in the first row and after that, has one image per row. I have checked other posts, Where they mentioned that the bindView is called twice. Once for determining the size and the second time for positioning and drawing it.Please help or suggest if there is a way to fix the code to show only one image in the first row.

Please see the following code and let me know either to correct it or refer to a better method. Your help is appreciated very much -- Thank You.

```
TodoCursorAdapter.java
public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,        viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Tvres);






            /* do what you need with the cursor here */


            String iD = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String fn = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fname"));
            String mn = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mname"));
            String ln = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lname"));
            String ssno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ssn"));

            String res = (ln + " " + ", " + fn +"                  "+ ssno.substring(5,9));
            //res_ArrayList.add(res);
            Log.d("Testing Cursor", res);

            tv1.setText(res);





    }

}

The MainActivity where the TodoCursorAdapter is called:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SQLiteOpenHelper SQLITEOPENHELPER;
    SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;



    ListView Lv;


    Context ctx = this;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /* Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.*/
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();


        if (bar != null) {
            //bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new   ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#151B54")));
           // bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000080")));
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF9900")));
        }

        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        bar.setTitle(R.string.main);
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.show();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
       ImageView imV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Imv);

        DatabaseOperations dbo = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);

       Cursor cursor = dbo.getInfo(dbo);
        TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
        Lv.setAdapter(todoAdapter);



}
```

}

[image: Duplicate Image in the First row]

Comment: Please help recommend if there is any way to use SQlite Cursor to load ListView.

Comment: Can I add the cursor values using Array List? Please help!